# Compile gradle with two configuration

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, launch4j, shadowjar

I have a gradle project. This project contains many modules.
I would like to make 2 differents executables with some module activated or not.
I have one executable with module1 and module2 like follow:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':module1')
    compile project(':module2')
}
```

I would like a executable with module1 and module2, and another one with only module1.

For generate an executable I used launch4j and shadowjar.

How I can do that?

Thanks

Comment: with a single gradle build command ?

Comment: Yes, with a single gradle task.

Answer (score 3):

You could possibly use my [java-flavours-plugin](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-java-flavours)

```
plugins {
    id "com.lazan.javaflavours" version "1.2"
}
javaFlavours {
    flavour 'version1'
    flavour 'version2'
}
dependencies {
    compile 'some:common-dependency:1.0'
    version1Compile project(':module1')
    version2Compile project(':module2')
}
```

Each flavour (eg version1 & version2) will have a jar task, the jar could be consumed by downstream modules/tasks. You can also reference `sourceSets.version1.runtimeClasspath` etc.

Note: The plugin supports flavour specific java sources and resources. Not sure if you need that feature.

Comment: Agree, previously we would create just another jar task and just spit out 2 artifacts.

Comment: If there's no flavour specific sources/resources then the jars should be exactly the same, it's the transitive dependencies that will be different

Comment: When I add your code I have the following error message: 
Could not find method version1Compile() for arguments [project ':module1'] on project 


I don't really understand how i can create my task?

task version1Compile() {
    sourceSets.version1.runtimeClasspath
    tasks = ['launch4j']
}

Comment: Looks like you're doing quite different to what I suggested. The plugin will already create a compile task for each flavour. See [here](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-java-flavours) to see what tasks and configurations are created per flavour.